# Storing data in multiple pivot tables in Laravel and Livewire

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, laravel-livewire

I am working on three tables that have two pivot tables in between. It's a workbook that has a many to many relationship with stations and the same workbook that has a many to many with clients. Right now I have a page where you can save a new workbook and you can select all the stations that should be related to it and also the client that should be associated with that workbook.
I figured I would only need to use the store in workbook since that would be the table that connects them both.

```
public function store(StoreWorkbookRequest $request)
    {
        $workbook = Workbook::create($request->only('wrkb_name'));
        
        $workbook->stations()->sync($request->input('stations', []));
        $workbook->clients()->sync($request->input('clients', []));

        return redirect()->route('admin.workbooks.create')->with('success', 'Successfully Created a New Workbook');
    }
```

I am also using livewire and I have the form for create in a livewire component.

```
    <form action="{{route('admin.workbooks.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          @csrf


            <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Workbook Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="wrkb_name">
            </div>


        <table class="table-auto w-full mb-6">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="px-4 py-2"></th>
              @if($showRate)
              <th wire:click="sortBy('SFM_rate')" style="cursor: pointer;" class="px-4 py-2">SFM Rate @include('partials.sort-icon',['field'=>'SFM_rate'])</th>
                @endif
                @if($showLetter)
              <th wire:click="sortBy('call_letter')" style="cursor: pointer;" class="px-4 py-2">Call Letter @include('partials.sort-icon',['field'=>'call_letter'])</th>
              @endif
              
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @foreach($stations as $key => $station)
              <tr>
                <td class="border px-4 py-2">
                    <input wire:model="selected" value="{{ $station->id }}" type="checkbox">
                </td>
                @if($showRate)
                <td class="border px-4 py-2">{{$station->SFM_rate}}</td>
                @endif
                @if($showLetter)
                <td class="border px-4 py-2">{{$station->call_letter}}</td>
                @endif
              </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
            {!! $stations->links() !!}
        @else
            <p class="text-center"> No stations were found</p>
        @endif
        <div class="w-full flex pb-10" >
            <div class="w-1/6 relative mx-1">
                <select wire:model="clientselected"  class="block appearance-none w-full bg-gray-200 border border-gray-200 text-gray-700 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="grid-state">
                            <option value="" >Select a Client</option>           
                            @foreach($clients as $id => $client)
                                <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $client->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                </select>
     
            </div>
            <div class="w-1/6 relative mx-1 space-x-6">
                <button class="block appearance-none w-full bg-black border border-gray-200 text-white py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500">Create Workbook</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

When I submit the form only the workbook is created and the two pivot tables remain unchanged.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Perhaps your $request->input() does not have the info you expect

Comment: I'm not familiar with livewire, wouldn't your selects still need a name property?

Comment: In the beginning of the `store` method, put `dd($request->input('stations'));` and give us the output. It must be an array like `[1, 2, 3]`, if it is something else, it won't work for you. Also make sure that the array items are all **int** not **string**.

Comment: Indeed I tried debugging and it looks like there is nothing passed on, but I don't know for sure where the problem is, the array is empty

Comment: In livewire I could have an array "selected" that would help me bulk delete the stations and that one works. I am not sure if I should do this whole store using livewire although that seems a bit more complicated since I have both the laravel controllers and the livewire component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. I added in my selectors the name="stations[]" and name="clients[]"

```
<input  name="stations[]" wire:model="selected" value="{{ $station->id }}" type="checkbox">
```

```
<select name="clients[]" wire:model="clientselected"  class="block appearance-none w-full bg-gray-200 border border-gray-200 text-gray-700 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="grid-state">
```

Now all the data is getting sent.

Comment: can you please share the full code